# Trying to upload image but getting error

Tags: thymeleaf

```
<img th:src="@{resources\static\images\Desert.jpg}"  text**height="15%"width="15%"/>
```

I am trying to view an image on website but I'm getting an error. This is Thymeleaf.

Error on Google console:

> GET http://localhost:8080/appstore/resources/static/images/Desert.jpg 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the path is coming from database, If so then you can try this

**code**

```
 <img th:src="${eachObject.image}" width="50px" height="30px"/>
```

So `eachObject` is a list of object which you get while iterating.This should work fine.